# How to change the push button label text and add a new functionality in runtime? Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, triggers, oracleforms

I'm learning Oracle Forms and Reports, This time I would like to coding within a push button some functionalities. I've added a push button named "Filter" for active the "enter_query" mode to add some search criteria using "WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED" trigger in item level and adding code within this trigger. It's too easy to code:

```
BEGIN 
  ENTER_QUERY; 
END;
```

But now, I have to add two new functionalities to this button:

1- First, When I write some search criteria and after push in the second button named "SEARCH" to retrieve data relationated the button "filter" have to rename to "LAST  RECORD" and if I press "LAST RECORD" button the form should to retrieve only  the last record retrieved of the las search. I've think about how I should to  resolve this problem and I've tried to add SET_ITEM_PROPERTY to trigger but  it is not working correctly.

```
BEGIN 
   ENTER_QUERY; 
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('BLOCK_NAME', LABEL, 'LAST RECORD'); 
   LAST_RECORD;
END;
```

2- And finally, after press in "LAST RECORD" button, It should to rename to "CANCEL" and if I press in this button one more time it should to clear the form and start again in the first position named "FILTER" to start a new search criteria as many time as the client want to do it...

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may edit this *snippet* :

```
begin 
     if ( :system.mode = 'ENTER-QUERY' ) then
           set_item_property('b_search', label, 'search'); 
           go_block('blk_yours');
           execute_query;    
     else
           set_item_property('b_search', label, 'last record');         
           go_block('blk_yours');    
           enter_query;
     end if;    
           last_record;
end;
```

*in* `when-button-pressed` *trigger of the item* `b_search`

Comment: sir, I tried to add this script to my trigger and I think it will work great but i have a question. What is the best way to add the code for retrieve only the last record of the query? thanks.

Comment: oh, i've edited "last_record" in the answer that i forgot. By the way i supposed that you would retrieve the whole record set and "last_record" stands only to go to the last row of grid. I couldn't understand why you wanna see only the last one, tell me please.

Comment: because it is part of a trainning to join to the smalll software company. Later I will add a screenshot showing the form because it is not working and i think I express my question too wrong and if I past a screenshot people can understand me. Thanks for your replies Barbaros. i continue trying.

Comment: Hi sir, I've reading about Oracle Forms build-ins and methods like GET_ITEM_PROPERTY and its attributes, It helped me to finish my test. I appreciate your time to reply many times. I will check your answer right. Thanks again!