# How to add counter on Button Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I create a new form in which user select "CSV" File then upload "CSV" data into oracle forms. I want when user press the "UPLOAD" Button then show count on Button Like "UPLOAD [1]". After upload data then button goes to disable. When delete data then again "UPLOAD" goes to enable. After again upload data then button like "UPLOAD [2]"

I don't know how to add counter on button. I search on google but nothing found.

I am using Oracle Forms 11gR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an upload button with the code :

```
declare
  v_toggled pls_integer;
begin
  insert into table1
  values(1,0);
  commit;
  select count(*) into v_toggled from table1 where closed = 0;
  if v_toggled >0 then
  Set_Item_Property('push_button1',label,'upload'||'['||v_toggled||']');
  end if;
  Go_Item('another_item');
  Set_Item_Property('push_button1',enabled,property_false);
end;
```

where table1 is created through `create table table1( id int,closed int);`

and
apply `update table1 set closed  = 1` during the exit from the form, and add

```
  Set_Item_Property('push_button1',enabled,property_true);
```

in the code of an other item where you want to refresh the activeness of that button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set the button's label dynamically in your code.
e.g.

> set_item_property('my_button', label, 'UPLOAD ['||my_counter||']');

You can check this [other SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085178/how-to-change-the-push-button-label-text-and-add-a-new-functionality-in-runtime) for some guidance.

Also use the Forms Builder offline documentation as everything you should know about is in it.